# On a heavy text page, the wrapper doesn't go to the very bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, height, containers, wrapper

For some reason, i can't seem to get the wrapper on a blog page of my site to go to the bottom of the page or to hold the text inside it without it going outside of it.

I created 2 wrappers as seen elsewhere but hasn't helped on this page.

Here is the HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapperfull">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header"> <a href="index.html"><img src="../Images/Header.png" width="379" height="99" alt="Just Joel Header"></a>
            </div>
            <!-- <div id="uberbar"> -->
            <div class="navigation">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href='#'><span>WORK</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="services1"> <a href="../../print.html">PRINT</a>
                                    <a href="../../branding.html">BRANDING</a>
                                    <a href="../../editorial.html">EDITORIAL</a>
                                    <a href="../../photography.html">PHOTOGRAPHY</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="inspired.html">INSPIRED</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="blog-container">
                    <h1>BLOG</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer congue consectetur lacus, quis facilisis elit faucibus nec. Nam aliquam nisi elit, nec venenatis lorem feugiat id. Sed in feugiat enim, ac condimentum mi. Etiam ut elit vulputate, posuere velit vitae, aliquam lorem. Proin tempor massa enim, in sollicitudin diam suscipit sed. Phasellus ut consectetur ipsum, quis sagittis velit. In tincidunt consectetur magna vitae vehicula. Cras vitae adipiscing lorem. Maecenas fermentum sapien leo.</p>
                <p>Nulla urna nibh, pulvinar quis viverra sit amet, semper at mi. Fusce adipiscing purus odio, rhoncus viverra enim accumsan eget. Donec nisi augue, dapibus at facilisis in, facilisis et urna. Suspendisse ornare, libero id egestas lobortis, magna est rutrum erat, at viverra nisi turpis sit amet nulla. Nam quis elit at augue aliquam malesuada. Nulla mi purus, commodo eu massa ut, luctus adipiscing justo. Duis sagittis nisl et erat sollicitudin tempus. Vivamus hendrerit et diam ut dictum. Proin arcu nunc, imperdiet id elementum eu, adipiscing non erat. Nullam risus dui, interdum non feugiat sed, ultricies eget lectus.</p>
                <p>Duis tincidunt purus sit amet arcu ullamcorper, a consectetur dolor vehicula. Aliquam a velit metus. Donec molestie euismod mauris et ultrices. Phasellus pellentesque pharetra nibh tempor tempor. Fusce rhoncus nibh eget est eleifend varius. Ut scelerisque enim facilisis tellus vulputate tempor. Quisque id pellentesque eros, ac tristique odio. Curazitur tincidunt gravida sapien nec porttitor.</p>
                <p>Pellentesque id eros viverra, aliquam tortor vitae, semper sapien. Duis sagittis fermentum metus. Nunc nisi nulla, mollis ut lacus vitae, adipiscing mollis ligula. Nulla aliquet tempor metus at blandit. Sed suscipit pulvinar purus, vel venenatis diam. Vestibulum aliquam, dolor ac lobortis blandit, mi augue mollis nisl, ac euismod orci est et nulla. Morbi congue risus eu justo pellentesque, quis vestibulum lorem porttitor. Vestibulum facilisis ultrices ultrices. Nam gravida neque quis lacinia pretium. Donec sem turpis, dictum sed tellus eu, aliquet faucibus erat. Quisque elementum purus vitae tellus vestibulum, convallis consectetur tortor vulputate. Vestibulum sollicitudin enim nec hendrerit egestas. Vivamus elementum mollis erat, eget placerat ligula aliquam nec. Donec pharetra elementum ligula et bibendum. Mauris tristique commodo viverra.</p>
                <p>Sed in justo mi. Nam iaculis, urna vitae fringilla rutrum, urna libero eleifend nulla, id pretium tellus nulla sit amet dui. Donec non sagittis dui, non posuere mi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vestibulum dui nulla, convallis ac dui ut, malesuada vulputate justo. Integer lacinia magna leo, eu lacinia est tempus eget. Cras ullamcorper mi non eros cursus, sed suscipit erat volutpat. Duis blandit, dolor vitae adipiscing tempor, massa massa consequat nibh, scelerisque volutpat risus massa vitae leo. Nullam id sem nibh. Aliquam porta nunc accumsan leo tristique pharetra. Morbi aliquet, ipsum sed accumsan ultricies, enim tellus venenatis tellus, sed tempus neque enim vitae tortor. Donec quis turpis ac elit facilisis viverra cursus eu felis. Suspendisse laoreet lacinia tortor, congue ullamcorper libero feugiat at. Integer fermentum in erat sed sollicitudin.</p>Pellentesque turpis nibh, egestas fermentum libero id, tincidunt hendrerit felis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam ac sem eget libero feugiat accumsan. Sed vel turpis eu elit adipiscing fermentum. Vivamus at velit hendrerit justo semper luctus. Etiam arcu erat, bibendum a nisl porta, adipiscing feugiat sem. Morbi tincidunt imperdiet sapien eu suscipit. Praesent sit am`enter code here`et hendrerit augue. Phasellus vel vulputate ante, hendrerit rhoncus dolor. Proin tempus eu tellus hendrerit vehicula. Donec elementum sed nibh non pellentesque. In lacinia, nisi consequat congue feugiat, diam mauris egestas lacus, ut tempor arcu mauris vehicula nisl. Nulla eu pulvinar odio. Mauris ac ligula luctus, ullamcorper nisl tempor, luctus risus. Praesent quis interdum velit. Proin in molestie nisl. Suspendisse ut elit imperdiet magna pellentesque facilisis eu ac dolor. Fusce sollicitudin vulputate urna eget ultrices. Quisque nisi nibh, lacinia et justo nec, gravida tincidunt nulla. Donec quis nulla at nisl congue sagittis. Aliquam sit amet mi vel justo blandit scelerisque sed quis dui. Praesent fringilla mollis nulla, sit amet aliquam dui euismod ac. Nunc non rutrum augue. Nulla vitae tincidunt lacus. Mauris turpis lacus, suscipit ac nisi eget, tristique malesuada metus. Sed nisi eros, accumsan ac eros ac, luctus mollis sem.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">   <a href="http://twitter.com/JustJoel_"><img src=http://i1286.photobucket.com/albums/a604/JustJoel_/TwitterSocialMediaIcon_zps379a327e.png width="40" height="40" alt="Twitter"></a>
    <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=119632044&amp;goback=.nmp_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1&amp;trk=spm_pichttp://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=119632044&amp;goback=.nmp_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1_*1&amp;trk=spm_pic"><img src=http://i1286.photobucket.com/albums/a604/JustJoel_/LinkedinSocialMediaIcon_zps134a0ab5.png width="40" height="40" alt="Linkedin"></a>
    <a href="http://pinterest.com/justjoel80/boards/"><img src=http://i1286.photobucket.com/albums/a604/JustJoel_/PinterestSocialMediaIcon_zps9d3a3e93.png width="40" height="40" alt="Pinterest"></a>
    <a href="http://instagram.com/mole80"><img src=http://i1286.photobucket.com/albums/a604/JustJoel_/InstagramSocialMediaIcon_zpsdd09d3a4.png width="40" height="40" alt="Instagram"></a>
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/107489686537237947777/posts"><img src=http://i1286.photobucket.com/albums/a604/JustJoel_/GooglePlusSocialMediaIcon_zps9d93776b.png width="41" height="40" alt="Googleplus"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is the CSS

```
       #wrapperfull {
       height: 100%;
       width: 1050px;
       margin: auto;
       margin-bottom: 0px;
       padding: 30px;
       background-color: #FFF;
       }

       #wrapper {
       height: auto;
       position: absolute;
       width: 1050px;
       margin-left: -30px;
       margin-bottom: 0px;
       padding: 30px;
       background-color: #FFF;
       }

        .blog-container {
       height: 1000px;
       width: 1050px;
       margin-top: 37px;
       background-color:
       }
```

#### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ebGJU/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is holding me back, thanks

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? Have the background stretch 100% height?

Comment: Have the wrapper stretch to 100% height and even by setting that it only does it on some pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow Up: Try this reworked solution. The page will fill the browser window if there is only a small amount of content, and expand if there is long content. It also has a sticky footer that will always stay at the bottom of the page, regardless of content size.

Here's a JSFiddle, with simplified code: http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/FjCsq/

---

First, 0 out the `html` and `body` in your css, and add `height:100%;`.

```
html{
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:none;
height:100%;
}

body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:none;    
height:100%;
}
```

Second, you'll only need one wrapper. Remove the "wrapper" div from the html and css. Since your page sections are already neatly contained in divs (header, navigation, blog-container, footer), you won't need it, and it complicates using min-height:100% in the step below. Now "wrapperfull" is your main container div.

Third, add `min-height:100%` to `wrapperfull`. Also include your width, and center the div. With min-height:100%, and the height set on the html and body, your page will expand to fit long content, and will fill the browser window if there is little content. 
Height 100% Div Article: http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/100-height-layout-using-css/comment-page-5/

You'll need to keep padding, border, and margin at 0. This prevents wrapperfull from becoming bigger than its assigned size (remember that the size includes margins, padding, borders, along with the content.
Box Model: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Since the width is set in wrapperfull, you don't need to set "width: 1050px" in your other divs. This will prevent your divs from spilling out. In the original code, the "width: 1050px" divs became larger once padding and margins were assigned (the Box Model again).

```
#wrapperfull {
min-height: 100%;
width: 1050px;
padding: 0;
border: none;
margin: 0px auto;
background-color: LightGray;
position: relative; /* for the absolute positioned footer */
}
```

Fourth, now you can style your header, navigation and blog-container. There is a background for the header, navigation and footer. The blog-container will use the wrapperfull background, and appear flexible.

```
#header {
padding: 10px;
background-color: PaleTurquoise;
}

.navigation {
padding:10px;
background-color: DarkGray;}

 /* the bottom padding needs to be taller than the footer, otherwise the text will slide behind the footer */
.blog-container {
padding: 20px 20px 80px 20px;
}
```

Fifth, now comes the sticky footer. Assign it position:absolute, bottom. The footer contents were wrapped in another div for styling, and to prevent overflow. You may need to play with the height. If it's too short, the contents will overflow and push the page down, causing a scrollbar.

```
#footer {
position: absolute;
width: 1050px;
height: 65px;
bottom: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background-color: DimGray;
}

.footer-style {
padding:10px;
}
```

Sticky Footer: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Position Absolute and Relative: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

---

The closing li tag for the Work menu item, along with the opening p tag in the last paragraph are missing, so see if its missing in your real code.

Comment: Hi, i need the wrapper div to go right to the bottom on all pages, regardless of how long they are and how much text/pictures are held in the container divs within the wrapper. Currently they stop too early on some pages. Thanks for your help, will try these.

Comment: Try the updated answer above. This should adapt to your varying content sizes. You can hold down the Ctrl key while pressing + or -, and see how it behaves at different sizes.

Comment: Thanks, that was a big help, the only thing now is i have a page of pictures going down it that don't sit within the wrapper or container so will have to work that out

Comment: Cheers, yes it's width on the picture container

Comment: Great, sounds like you found the issue. If there's still an overflow problem, just leave a comment.